# J2EE app needs .java to run, .class not enough?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar

I'm trying to run a j2ee application and eclipse gives me an error saying "the jar file  has no source attachments". This is a jar this application depends on. I extracted the jar and see only class files, but that should be enough to run this application, no?

Comment: Is that an error preventing it from running?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using a JRE and not a JDK to run Eclipse. One way to fix this is to add a JDK to the list of JREs (Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs).

Comment: no, that wasn't it.  I still get the same error.  In any case a jre is all that is needed to run if you have the .class files because they're already compiled.